# Contests vs. Writing Competitions

Tags: discussion, retagging

Someone just posted a new question [Should a short story be submitted to a publisher in order to know if they would be interested in a book based on it?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44945/should-a-short-story-be-submitted-to-a-publisher-in-order-to-know-if-they-would) where they used the tag [writing-competitions](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-competitions)

I found this strange because we already have [contests](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contests), a long-standing tag with 16 questions, which  reads:

> This tag should be used for questions about writing contests. You
>   should specify what genre and length you are interested in.
>
> This tag should be used for questions about writing contests. You
>   should specify what genre, such as horror or comedy and what length,
>   such as short-story or novel, you are interested in.

[writing-competitions](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-competitions) is just over 10 months old and only has 3 questions.  The new one, a closed one, and one more.

So I switched those 3 questions to [contests](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contests)

This will allow [writing-competitions](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-competitions) to die out.  Unless someone wants to make it a synonym.

Comment: Makes sense these should be synonyms to me. At least competitions and contests. Which should show up when searching tags.

Comment: @linksassin I have no objections to this.  It would keep the competition tag from being recreated later.  But I also can't propose it or just do it either.  Need a mod.